# Azure-iot-edge edgehub not sending metrics unlike edgeAgent using Metric collector module

Tags: metrics, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I am new to Azure IOT edge and have been following few documentations on collecting metrics using metric collector module(mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-metrics-collector).

I am following option 2, from this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-collect-and-transport-metrics?view=iotedge-2020-11&tabs=iothub).

I have done all the necessary configurations as per this doc and I am receiving metrics from edgeAgent, but not from edgeHub. The error says connection refused.

I am using a Linux VM as an IOT edge device.
The upload target for my case is 'IoTMessage'. Hence LogAnalytics values are left empty. I have taken this example [file](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/release/1.1/edge-modules/metrics-collector/src/ExampleDeployment.json) as reference.

Am I missing something here to make it work?

I have already tried [edgeHub doesn't expose metrics](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/4210?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5002324) solution, but no luck.

logs below

```
[2022-03-25 09:24:08.635 INF] Starting periodic operation Scrape and Upload Metrics...
[2022-03-25 09:24:08.636 INF] Scraping endpoint http://edgeHub:9600/metrics
[2022-03-25 09:24:08.637 INF] Scraping endpoint http://edgeAgent:9600/metrics
[2022-03-25 09:24:08.641 ERR] Error scraping endpoint http://edgeHub:9600/metrics - System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Azure.Monitor.MetricsScraper.ScrapeEndpoint(String endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-modules/azure-monitor/src/MetricsScraper.cs:line 72

[2022-03-25 09:24:08.642 INF] Scraping finished, received 0 metrics from endpoint http://edgeHub:9600/metrics
[2022-03-25 09:24:08.645 INF] Scraping finished, received 171 metrics from endpoint http://edgeAgent:9600/metrics
```

Comment: which version of EdgeHub module are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.0.9.5

Comment: Well, Thanks for the hint, updated it to 1.2.8, and now receiving metrics from both the endpoint. GoodDay!

Comment: Hi Anish, could you please post your findings as an answer so that other members can get help from it in future.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, the issue was with older version of edge hub module which I had.
Once I deployed the latest version (1.2.8), I was able to receive metrics at both the endpoint.

If there's still connection refused error, [this](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/4210?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5002324) solution can also be tried.

please make sure adding route to edge hub something like this

```
 "FromMetricsCollectorToUpstream": "FROM /messages/modules/<Name_Of_Your MetricsCollector_Module>/outputs/* INTO $upstream",
```